# Is it allowed to assign to a dereferenced this (*this)?

Tags: c++

I'm currently refreshing my C++ skills and was wondering if it is possible to assign something to `*this`.
I know assigning to `this` is forbidden, but can't find the same information for my case.

An example:

```
class Foo {
  int x;
public:
  Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
  Foo incr() { return Foo(x+1); }
  void incr_() { (*this) = incr(); }
};
```

Edit: corrected `incr()`'s return type from `void` to `Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void incr() { return Foo(x+1); }`

This is invalid. You cannot return a `Foo` object from a function having `void` return type.

```
void incr_() { 

   (*this) = incr(); // This invokes Foo& operator = (const Foo& ) (compiler synthesized)
}
```

This is fine.

Comment: This would have been more suited as a comment than as an answer, IMO.

Comment: @Etienne : Lemme complete my answer first. `:)`

Comment: You are totally right, but I simply made a mistake there. I meant the function to be `Foo incr()`.

Comment: OK, now that the memory leak answer has enough downvotes for me to be sure, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can edit out the __no__ comment at the beginning now, since he changed the question

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is allowed, and it actually invokes your class' assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works. And `*this = x` is just syntactic sugar for `operator=(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, if `*this` return value is of a datatype that has an assignment operator defined.